# Does Rally the Righteous affect heroic?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I found [Rally the Righteous](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRally%20the%20Righteous%5d), and I'm wondering: are the creatures (after the first) being targeted to untap and does that affect heroic creatures?

And if I untap a multicoloured creature, like [Anax and Cymede](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAnax%20and%20Cymede%5d), does it effect red and white creatures or only red white creatures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rally the Righteous only targets *one* creature, and so it'll only trigger heroic on that specific creature. It says "untap target creature" — that's the one that gets targeted. It then further says "and each other creature that shares a color with it" — but it doesn't say "target" in that phrase anywhere, so you're not targeting any of those other creatures. (If it was targeting, it'd say something ike "each other target creature".)

If you target a multicolored creature, like the spell says, it'll affect any creature that shares *any* color with the one you untap. If you untap a red/white creature, you'll untap red creatures, white creatures, red/white creatures, red/blue, white/black, etc etc — because all of those have a color of at least red or white.